# Cursor disappearing after full screen

Tags: mouse, cursor

I have a mac laptop running 10.14.6. For some reason, in the last week, the cursor has started  disappearing every time I go full screen and then leave full screen. So I have to hit Mission Control every time to bring it back. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Could you please double check the macOS version and edit your question?